# Failed to parse declaration "background: url(1) : using styled components - React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm new to react native and I'm trying to use the "Imagebackground" using styled-components but I get an error on android when I tried to use it: "backgroundimage is not a valid style property. But on the browser(chrome) work fine, any idea how to fix this.

```
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import {View, Image, Text, TouchableOpacity, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants'; 

const StatusBarHeight = Constants.statusBarHeight;

// Background imgage
import bg from './../assets/imgs/bg.png'; 

// Colors
export const Colors = {
    primary: '#09487b',
};

const {primary} = Colors;
 
    
export const Content = styled.ImageBackground`
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: url(${bg});
  width: 2000px;
  height: 2000px;
`;
```

This is my Home page

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
 

import {
    StyledContainer,Content
} from "./../components/styles";


const Home = () => {
    return (  
        <Content>

        </Content>
    );
} 


export default Home;
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use require:

```
background-image: url(${require('./../assets/imgs/bg.png')});
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried oyr solution but I get the same error, I have updated my question with a screenshoot of the android emulator.

Comment: There's something wrong with your require. Make sure the image path is valid. Maybe it's `../../assets/img/bg.png`?

Comment: Thanks, I changed the path but I get a different error - now it said failed to parse declaration "background: url(1)